# Regex for not matching if the pattern captured in capturing group changes

Tags: regex, pcre

Given an input like `@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3`. I want to capture what is after `@2=` when `@3=B3` and also verify that when `@3=B3`, then `@2=` should contain the same value which was captured.

The patterns that should match are:

`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3`
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3`

The pattern that should not match 
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B10@3=B3`
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B10@3=B3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3`

The way I do this currently is in two passes, first by getting all invalid patterns by using regex `@2=((?:\w|-|'|""|,|\.)+?)@3=B3.+@2=(?!\1@)((?:\w|-|'|""|,|\.)+?)@3=B3` and then removing these patterns from all the available inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?:(?!@2=[^@]*@3=B3(?:[@>]|$)).)*@2=([^@]*)@3=B3(?:[@>]|$)(?!.*@2=(?!\1)[^@]*@3=B3(?:[@>]|$))
```

[Online demo.](https://regex101.com/r/MwOGDG/3)

#### How does it work?

First it skips all the text up until the first `@2=` followed by `@3=B3` using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/1222951):

```
^(?:(?!@2=[^@]*@3=B3(?:[@>]|$)).)*
```

Then it captures the value of the `@2=`:

```
@2=([^@]*)@3=B3(?:[@>]|$)
```

And finally it uses a negative lookahead assertion to make sure that no other `@2=` followed by a `@3=B3` has a different value than the captured one:

```
(?!.*@2=(?!\1)[^@]*@3=B3(?:[@>]|$))
```

Comment: Can we avoid ">" after B3. The real input have more dimensions like @4=..@5=......@100=..

Comment: @mohit Well, then replace the `>` with `@` or `[>@]` or whatever.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - After changing to @, if the @2=B2 is at the last of the string, it does not work. https://regex101.com/r/FGgk33/2. Can you please help

Comment: @mohit My bad, I overlooked that that could happen. Answer updated. Unfortunately fixing that bug increased the complexity of the regex quite a bit...